# Recompile an apk without changing the signature

Tags: java, android, apk, reverse-engineering, apktool

I am trying to change the name of the app using its APK, but the problem is when I decompile\recompile it (using apkeasytool) and install it, it crashes.
This behavior could be because when the app starts it somehow checks if the app is compiled with the original signature.

I have tried to see the app logic on Jadx but still, many method names and strings are encoded.
I know this is a way to protect APKs from repack but I know this can be cracked I am learning about Frida and let's see if I can crack that.
And if you have any suggestions please feel free to tell me.

Comment: What do you mean by decompile/recompile? An APK is signed, if you modify the APK, the signature checksum will not match. This is by design. You cannot alter an APK like that.

Comment: The APK signature is a cryptographic signature without known vulnerability. Therefore the only way to create an identical signature is to be in possession of the private key used to sign the APK. This means you would need to get the private key of the app developer which only the app develoe has or may be also Google in their app signing HSM.

Comment: @DavidWasser if that's the case, then how do people mod apps? like WhatsApp, Instagram, etc

Comment: @Robert how do people mob apps than?

Comment: People mod apps by simply ignoring the certificate and after recompiling the app resign it with a self-generated key. Most apps don't check if the signature is the one they expect to be signed with. Note that resigning the app will "disconnect" the app from Play Store which means all in-app purchases are not possible.

Comment: @Robert so I am trying to change the name of an App but after recompiling, it crashes, which means it is checking for the original signature,

Comment: is that right? if yes than what could be the possible solution to achieve the desired result,
which is to stop it from crashing after recompiling it.

Comment: @QasimMalik I don't understand your question. Only the author of an app (or the holder of the private key from the certificate that was used to sign the app) can modify that app. The author creates a new version and signs it with the same certificate that was used to sign the app before. This generates a new signed APK which can be installed over the existing installation.

Comment: I'll ask again, what do you mean by recompiling? And how does it crash? We need more details?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "change the name of the app"? Do you have the source code? Is this your app? How are you "changing the name"?

Comment: @DavidWasser Yes this is exactly what I do to upload my apps on Play Store but you know there exist mob versions of many famous apps, Do you have any idea how they decompile, make changes, and recompile the apps and still get it working?

Comment: @DavidWasser no the app is not mine, i have an apk of an app whose name is in Chinese language and I want to change the name to English.

Comment: And how is it crashing? What is the exception and stacktrace from logcat?

Comment: @DavidWasser  Do you know we can modify the design (XML) and even logic (sometimes) of an app if we only have an apk. This is how reverse engineering works.

Comment: @DavidWasser I do not have the source code, I don't have the stack trace. 
you need to understand how it works

Comment: You are missing the point of my question. You say that the app "crashes". If it crashes, it should be logging the reason for the crash including stacktrace to logcat. Look in the logcat when the app crashes and copy that into your question.

Comment: @DavidWasser if we have apk, we can change its extension to .zip and change its XML files (which include strings file) so we can change the name of any app without the source code

Comment: @DavidWasser I got your point but how can I get the logs from an apk?
hope you are getting my point.

Comment: No, you don't get the logs from APK! You put the APK on the device, run the app and it crashes. You get the logs from the device. You say the app is crashing after you modify it. I assume you mean that you put the modified APK on the device and run it and it crashes. If not, please explain what you are doing.

Comment: @DavidWasser do you have any experience with reverse engineering? I think you are overqualified for this question and i am unable to clear my point, if that's the case please tell me if I have only an apk file, randomly downloaded from a website into my android device, and when I installs it and try to open the installed app, it crashes, can I get the crash logs? i am not using any IDE, nothing just an apk file downloaded from the internet.

Comment: @DavidWasser leave it, I don't need help anymore 

Comment: Seems like you don't know the `adb logcat` command, the most basic command for retrieving log of all apps running on Android (unless the app has been built to not log anything to logcat).

Answer (score 0):

Use Apk Editor and Apktool-M on mobile to change the name